# Best way to describe "turning ideas into reality"

Tags: idioms, synonyms, vocabulary

I'd like to ask if sentence “We accelerate ideas” sounds odd or natural? What is the best word/phrasal to describe transformation of the ideas into reality/real things?

Comment: _"We create the future"_ sounds nice.

Comment: Request for personal preferences or suggestions make the question off-topic!!

Comment: "We accelerate ideas" sounds like corporate fluff; likely from a company ruled by the sales department.

Comment: Yes, the expression "we accelerate ideas" sounds odd, and does not convey the meaning you are after. To *accelerate* means to quicken something, in other words you are saying "we" make ideas go faster. Is that a good or bad thing?

Comment: “*We make ideas become reality*” is cliché, but it renders the meaning more accurately.

Comment: *Actualize* should work.

Answer (score 2):

[To materialize](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/materialised) can convey the idea:

> - To cause to become real or actual: By building the house, we materialized a dream.

Answer (score 2):

"He ***realized*** his grand idea in the form of..."

[Or, the more anachronistic but electrifying "***reified***"]

Answer (score 2):

Consider the verb *[execute](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/execute)*

> Carry out or put into effect (a plan, order, or course of action):
>   the corporation executed a series of financial deals [*Oxford Dictionary Online*]

The term is often used in business to indicate decisive implementation. The term *executive* is directly related, as one who is charged with bringing something to fruition. You might say

> *Some companies play with ideas. We execute.*

Similarly *[implement](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/implement)*

> Put (a decision, plan, agreement, etc.) into effect [ also *ODO*]

Answer (score 2):

We manifest reality where there were only dreams.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. On this site, answers are expected to provide *explanations*, including such references as may be appropriate. I encourage you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and to browse the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) the conventions here.

Answer (score 1):

**Flesh out** [1. [MWV] (tr) to give substance to (an argument, description, etc): Collins] is often used:

> the theorists have fleshed out a variety of scenarios [ODO]

'Realise' is a synonym of 'materialize', but both have more common senses and are thus perhaps a poorer choice.

Answer (score 1):

After experiencing a momentary lapse of "writer's block," a Google query to this post inspired me with the right word, which I’m compelled to share-*behold*-[**incarnate**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/incarnate?s=t):

> 1. "embodied in flesh; given a bodily, especially a human, form."
> 2. "personified or typified, as a quality or idea:
>      chivalry incarnate."
> 3. 'flesh-colored or crimson."
> 4. 'put (an idea or other abstract concept) into concrete form.'

Comment: How exactly is **incarnate** the right word? How should it be used? In addition to providing the definition, your answer should address the above points.

Comment: Implicitly, #4 satisfies the second-part of the question, "what is the best word/phrasal to describe transformation of the ideas into reality/real things?" so I was compelled to share the inspiration.  Thank you, @TowerofTesla.

Comment: (+1) You're welcome @ alexanderjsingleton

Answer (score 0):

"We accelerate ideas" sounds like a slogan or logo subtitle, of a company of the not so trustworthy kind.

The problem is that it is too general - a bad marketing department could apply this to every second company.

If you use it to actually describe "turning ideas into reality" - how should the reader know?

Answer (score 0):

**To turn ideas into reality** or **to concretise ideas** may fit.

"Concretise" means to render concrete; make real or specific; give tangible form to

Answer (score 0):

Make one's dreams come true

> something that happens that you have always hoped for
>  "Meeting you
>   is a dream come true for me."
>  [Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/a-dream-come-true)